# Lion - automatic file versioning - details

Tags: macos, versions

Can anybody explain some details about **how is implemented the automatic file versioning** in the Lion?

- It is transparent for any file? (for example, for files created in the Terminal.app with shell command like `ls >file.txt` and `ls -l > file.txt` mean than the `file.txt` got versioning?, or
- every application should call some `versioning API` at the save?

Comment: lion questions are currently off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only information has released to non-Mac Developer Program members is the following.

> If you have a document-based application, Lion offers an efficient, built-in auto save feature that stores changes to the working document instead of creating additional copies on a disk. Versions automatically records a history of changes made to your documents and lets your app display a Time Machine like interface so users can browse through previous versions. [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/whats-new.html)

There is more information available for Mac Developer Program subscribers. The information, however, is currently restricted by a non-disclosure agreement . The information will most likely be made available for everyone once the final version of Lion is released. This is how Apple have done it in the past.

Personally I am a bit disappointed that Apple chose to go with ‘something else’ instead of the native handling of this offered by the [ZFS file system.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/zfs-338092.html) (As rumored as far back as Leopard.)

Comment: ZFS would've been great from a technical perspective, but became a non-option the moment it was announced that Oracle might buy Sun.  AIUI there's just no way Apple was going to give Oracle that sort of licensing leverage.

Comment: Just browsed a bit and for now im sure than versioning will need support from developer, so the application must be built with some API to support versioning. It is **not** OS level.